Struggling with NSScrollView
I'm still discovering swift and the various frameworks. So I'm now trying to create scrolling composition with a grid - containing images - and an NSStackView at on top.
However, I'm running into a problem that might seem stupid, but when I try to wrap my NSCollectionView in another NSView and pointing the scrollView.documentView to, I can't scroll anymore... Even though it works fine when I set the scrollView.documentView to the NSCollectionView directly.
Working case:

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrollView = NSScrollView(frame: .zero)
        scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = true
        scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = false
        scrollView.scrollerStyle = .overlay
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        vStack = NSStackView(frame: .zero)
        vStack.orientation = .vertical
        vStack.spacing = 12 * 2
        vStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let hStack = NSStackView()
        hStack.orientation = .horizontal
        hStack.spacing = 12
        hStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let label1 = NSTextField(labelWithString: "Collection")
        
        hStack.addArrangedSubview(label1)
        
        let layout = PinterestLayout()
        layout.delegate = self
        
        collectionView = NSCollectionView(frame: .zero)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView
            .register(
                ArtCardCell.self,
                forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("ArtCardCell")
            )
        collectionView.backgroundColors = [.BG]
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
//        vStack.addArrangedSubview(hStack)
//        vStack.addArrangedSubview(collectionView)
        
        scrollView.documentView = collectionView

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                   scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                   scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                   scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                   scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
                   
//                   vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
//                   vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
//                   vStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
//                   vStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
//                   vStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
                   
                   collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
                   
//                   vStack.arrangedSubviews[0].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
//                   vStack.arrangedSubviews[0].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
//                   vStack.arrangedSubviews[0].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 80)
               ])
        
        collectionView.postsBoundsChangedNotifications = true
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didScroll(_:)),
                                               name: NSView.boundsDidChangeNotification,
                                               object: collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.contentView
        )
    }

collectionView   height: 3549.0
ScrollView       height: 628.0
StackView        height: --

Dysfunctional case:

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrollView = NSScrollView(frame: .zero)
        scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = true
        scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = false
        scrollView.scrollerStyle = .overlay
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        vStack = NSStackView(frame: .zero)
        vStack.orientation = .vertical
        vStack.spacing = 12 * 2
        vStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let hStack = NSStackView()
        hStack.orientation = .horizontal
        hStack.spacing = 12
        hStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let label1 = NSTextField(labelWithString: "Collection")
        
        hStack.addArrangedSubview(label1)
        
        let layout = PinterestLayout()
        layout.delegate = self
        
        collectionView = NSCollectionView(frame: .zero)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView
            .register(
                ArtCardCell.self,
                forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("ArtCardCell")
            )
        collectionView.backgroundColors = [.BG]
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        vStack.addArrangedSubview(hStack)
        vStack.addArrangedSubview(collectionView)
        
        scrollView.documentView = vStack

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                   scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                   scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                   scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                   scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
                   
                   vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
                   vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
                   vStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
                   vStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
                   vStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
                   
                   collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
                   
                   vStack.arrangedSubviews[0].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
                   vStack.arrangedSubviews[0].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
                   vStack.arrangedSubviews[0].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 80)
               ])
    }

collectionView   height: 508.0
ScrollView       height: 628.0
StackView        height: 628.0

If someone could give me some references in the doc or more direct help, I'd be more than grateful!

What are the constraints between vStack and scrollView supposed to do?

To be quite honest, I don't know; I'm just trying to do everything I can to solve the problem...

This question is similar to: Programmatic NSScrollView with layout anchors - how to fix the scrolling?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
